# What Object or Table in SFDC starts with and Id prefix of 0EM? Knowledge Articles and Attachments

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc, sfdc-metadata-api

What Object or Table in SFDC starts with and **Id** **prefix** of **0EM**?

I have uploaded an image into a Knowledge__kav object in Salesforce, which is basically the knowledge article page.

And when I open the link to the image, it gives an Id starting with **0EM**.

But, what table does the Id starting with **0EM** relate to?

The label for the object is **Other Uploaded Images and Files**

Comment: It's a hidden table, don't think it can be queried directly. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17894/rtaimage-servlet-parameters-what-does-the-refid-refer-to. What are you trying to do? You loaded the image into rich text field or as a real attachment / contentdocument? If it's in rtf payload it probably can be queried as that field and it'll be base64-encoded in there

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded it into Content Version instead and referred to the url as img src.